# What is the greater significance of the Boer War?

Tags: war, great-britain, boer-war

The Boer Wars are generally viewed as a minor conflict affecting only South Africa; I, however, am skeptical about this. Britain did, after all, send nearly half a million soldiers to fight in the Boer Wars. So I'm wondering, *how* did the Boer Wars affect the tide of world history elsewhere? I remember reading about how they affected Allied tactics during Word War I; but beyond that I'm in the dark.

*What is the significance of the Boer Wars outside of South Africa?*

Comment: I'd think there ought to be a way to narrow this question a bit to make it on-topic. It would be nice to have a good Boer Wars question here.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question and voted to re-open.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I placed the new boer-war tag on several relevant questions, so there is now a a whole section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Boer War was something of a flashpoint for World War I. For instance, Kaiser Wilhelm II of Germany sent congratulations in the so-called [Kruger Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruger_telegram), to Boer President Paul Kruger after an early Boer victory, inflaming British public opinion.

More to the point, the conclusion of the Boer War produced a moderate peace that led to a reconciliation between British and Boer that formed the [Union of South Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_South_Africa) in 1910, merging the two British provinces (Cape Province and Natal) with the two Boer provinces (Transvaal and Orange Free State) into a single entity. A few years later, [General Jan Christian Smuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Smuts), an important Boer general in the Boer War led the combined "South African" forces against German South West Africa (Namibia) in 1914.